# Is there some Plone content type already available for HTML5 animations, videos etc.?

Tags: html, animation, plone, plone-4.x, archetypes

I have a Plone based site with some custom Archetypes-based content types. Now we feel the need to support HTML5-based animations etc. for new multimedia contents.

Is there some suitable content type already, or should we invent it on our own?

AFAICS, it will look like this:

- There is some common `createJs.js` file somewhere which provides the API which is used for all HTML5 multimedia contents.
- Each multimedia object features some Javascript code (which could be saved as a file `animation.js` somewhere)
- The same directory which holds the `animation.js` file will contain all further resources needed, e.g. images.
- The view HTML code will need to `src` the `animation.js` file (which will in turn "create" the animation).

So, is there some object type already I should use?

If there isn't - should I put everything into the ZODB, or would it be better to store the resources plainly in the server file system (and let Apache serve them more or less directly)?

Comment: You generally will have better luck asking questions in https://community.plone.org

Comment: Yes - thanks for [linking my question](https://community.plone.org/t/stack-overflow-is-there-some-plone-content-type-already-available-for-html5-animations-videos-etc/3691?u=tobiasherp) there!

Answer (score 1):

For video and audio you can just use the `File` content type and modify the templates to use the HTML5 `video` and `audio` tags, which make use of browser-built-in video and audio players.

`plone.app.contenttypes` is doing that, but this is Dexterity based. However, it can give you some hints: https://github.com/plone/plone.app.contenttypes/blob/master/plone/app/contenttypes/browser/templates/file.pt

Also, you have to provide the video and audio files in a web-suitable format: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats

For custom JavaScript code you rather need a custom Plone application. For that you do not need a specific content type except a custom content type if you need animation-specific configuration options to be passed to the JavaScript. Otherwise a simple view which includes the JavaScript will do it. For more information on these topics consult the Plone documentation: https://docs.plone.org/4/en/develop/plone/views/browserviews.html

Disclaimer: The docs above refer to use Grok, which I would not recommend as this is not have Plone core support. We need to get the docs updated there.

Comment: I have a `portal_type` for animations already; currently it usually features an XML and `.swf` file. It is currently not "folderish" to hold an arbitrary number of  needed files. So I'll add some option to choose the animation style and add some support to store the javascript and resource files.

Comment: For folderish types, this could help you: https://github.com/collective/collective.folderishtypes

Comment: The docs *still* refer to Grok? Buh. I would fix that, but since every single contribution of mine to the docs had been overwritten silently: Nah, screw that.